# Create a DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator

Tags: android, android-animation

Android provides the following animation interpolators: AccelerateInterpolator, DecelerateInterpolator, AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator.

How can I achieve a DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator?

Comment: i see you even didn't bother to ask uncle google...

Comment: if its that obvious. next time take the time to add a link instead of taking the time to point out that its simple.

Comment: @JY2k here you are http://www.google.com/search?q=DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=cr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an interpolator that goes fast at the start and end but slow in the middle ?

Find the proper math function that represents your interpolator and implement the Interpolator interface with your math function.

Example from http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1078

```
public class DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator implements Interpolator {
  public DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator() {}
  public float getInterpolation(float t) {
    float x=2.0f*t-1.0f;
    return 0.5f*(x*x*x + 1.0f);
  }
}
```

Or combine a DecelerateInterpolator following by and AccelerateInterpolator.

```
public class DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator implements Interpolator {
  final float factor;
  public DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator() {
    this(1);
  }

  public DecelerateAccelerateInterpolator(float factor) {
    this.factor = factor;
  }

  public float getInterpolation(float t) {
    if (t < 0.5f) {
      return new DecelerateInterpolator(factor).getInterpolation(2 * t);
    } else {
      return new AccelerateInterpolator(factor).getInterpolation(2 * (t - 0.5f));
    }
  }
}
```